# Problem with reading lines in TXT File, for line in

Tags: python

I have a problem which don't let me to make a Login System.
What I want to do here is Open the TXT file, and search for Username and Password in one line. If the password and Username is in the one Line, the login is successful, we can continue.
My code:

```
elif "l" in Register_Login or "L" in Register_Login:
        check = True
        while open(Database, mode = 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        Vardas = input("Please enter your Username!\n")
        Password = getpass.getpass("Please enter your Password!\n")
        for line in f:
            if("Vardas : " + Vardas + " Password : " + Password + " ") == line.strip():
                print("You're logged in")
                check = False
                break;
            else:
                print("Wrong Combination!")
                continue;
```

My TXT File Lines.
[image]

EDIT** 
After editing some code, I get another error.

```
elif "l" in Register_Login or "L" in Register_Login:
    check = True
    with open('Registruoti.txt', mode = 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        Vardas = input("Please enter your Username!\n")
        Password = getpass.getpass("Please enter your Password!\n")
    for line in f:
        if("Vardas : " + Vardas + " Password : " + Password + " ") == line.strip():
            print("You're logged in")
            check = False
            break;
        else:
            print("Wrong Combination!")
            continue;
```

[image: ERROR2]

Comment: Write your filename completely in open() as string: "filename.txt".

Comment: Updated, more error came.

Comment: As you see error says: I/O operation on closed file. you must set every operation on your file in <with> block.

Comment: Don't post images of errors. You should probably accept the answer you got and ask a new question rather than update your post with new questions as you go. But of course, search before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supposed to work, the correct way to use a context manager is by using `with` keyword, not `while`. Also preserve the correct indentation after using a context manager.

Comment: That, was my mistake, but when trying to log in. For example username - Jut password - jut. From the TXT File, but i always get the false, that that Wrong combination.

Comment: You are comparing string
`"Vardas : " + Vardas + " Password : " + Password + " "`
to the entire line from that txt file, which also holds other values, such as `Balance` or `RegTime`.
Therefore, it will always result in false. You should check if this login and password is IN (included) in that textfile line.
`"Vardas : " + Vardas + " Password : " + Password + " " in line.strip()`

Comment: Regarding your seccond "issue": you need to perform operations on that file under `with` statement in the correct indentation level. Else, you are exiting the textfile context manager, so the file is no longer open. If you want to perform operations on the file, do so in the correct indentation level.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me to fix the code. Also one more question : After this operation i should use f.close()?

Comment: No, if you are using a context manager then there is no such a need.

Normally without the `with` keyword you would have to perform an .open() and .close() operation on the file. However, using `with open()` makes sure that the file is closed correctly after leaving the indentation level under that context manager.
To grasp the idea of how context managers work, read up on them here:
https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/
And if you are satisfied with my answer, don't forget to accept it. :)